# Save string from firestore to variable

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a value from firestore and save it to a variable in flutter. I tried using StreamBuilder, but since i am not building a widget it does not work.

To clarify my problem, I am trying to get a url from a firestore document and then open it when i press a button in the app.

I also tried to adapt code i found in another question, but that returns null.

```dart
Future _getUrl() async{
    DocumentReference docRef = Firestore.instance.collection('information').document('pdf');
    var data;
    docRef.get().then((datasnapshot){
        data = datasnapshot.data['url'];
    });
    return data;
  }
```

The collection is called *information*, the document *pdf*, and the field *url*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will return null because you are not waiting for the get() future to return before you return data. docRef.get() is a Future, so it will execute asychronously. Meanwhile, your program will move on to the next line, which is return data.

Something like this would do what you want I think:

```
Future _getUrl() async{
  DocumentReference docRef = Firestore.instance.collection('information').document('pdf');
  return docRef.get().then((datasnapshot){
    return datasnapshot.data['url'];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `_getUrl` is already marked as `async` you can also use `await` in its body to return the right value:

```
Future _getUrl() async {
  DocumentReference docRef = Firestore.instance.collection('information').document('pdf');
  await datasnapshot = docRef.get();
  let data = datasnapshot.data['url'];
  return data;
}
```